# Помогите записать массив объектов в ison и потом обратно из ison в массив объектов java

Tags: java, json

суть проблемы в следующем, у меня есть 'private ObservableList personData' что бы записать из этой коллекции данные в json я коллекция помещаю в массив затем массив сохраняю в файл json...все нормально сохраняется

```
public void savePersonDataToFile(File file) {

        Person [] temp = new Person[personData.size()];
        temp = personData.toArray(temp);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String string = gson.toJson(temp);
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getPath())) {
            fileWriter.write(string);
            setPersonFilePath(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Ошибка");
            alert.setHeaderText("Файл не сохранен!!!");
            alert.setContentText("Данные в файле:\n" + file.getPath()+"не сохранились");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
```

но обратно достать массив объектов из файла не получается, создает массив null
вот пример кода который я использую

```
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
        String jonson = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
        Person[] temp = gson.fromJson(reader, Person[].class);

       System.out.println(jonson);
       System.out.println(file.getPath());
       System.out.println(temp+" размер - " );

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Could not load data");
        alert.setContentText("Could not load data from file:\n" + file.getPath());

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
```

что я делаю не правильно?
 путь к файлу распечатывается, строка json распечатывается а массив не создается.

Comment: В сохранённом json-файле данные есть?

Comment: да файл сохраняется и файле есть тект очень похожий на json (если смотреть в блокноте...да и строка String jonson имеет тот же текст в виде json

Comment: В этом _тексте очень похожем на json_ есть данные из `personData`?

Comment: текст...[{"firstName":{"name":"","value":"Hans","valid":true,"helper":{"observable":{}}},"lastName":{"name":"","value":"Muster"...и так далее...это пример этого текста, и в нем присутствуют данные которые мне нужны...меня смущает вот это ""..{"observable":{}}}"" теоретически этого не должно быть в тексте json

Comment: вот сейчас сохранился еще раз файл создался и сохранился но в консольку выкинуло такое сообщение про ошибку...

Comment: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory (file:/C:/Users/%d0%91%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b6/Downloads/gson-2.3.1.jar) to field javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty.bean
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: Похоже проблема в том что я в классе Person использую тип данный StringProperty  (это мне нужно для того что бы заполнять таблицу данными в  javaFX использую TableView

Comment: вот теперь не знаю что делать...создать еще один промежуточный класс (но уже с обычным String)  и коллекцию или массив по типу этого класса...и каждый раз при записи/чтении гонять туда обратно? что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

похоже дело в том, что вы пытаетесь повторно прочитать поток (`reader`).

```
    String jonson = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    Person[] temp = gson.fromJson(reader, Person[].class);
```

надо заменить на

```
    String jonson = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    Person[] temp = gson.fromJson(jonson, Person[].class);
```

т.о. gson будет парсить уже считанную строку, а не пытаться прочитать из прочитанного потока.

Comment: точно....но я пробовал и ваш вариант, и все равно не работало...возможно потому , что у меня не была соблюдена кодировка при записи в файл ...на данный момент решил проблему по другому, в классе Person написал метод toString и записываю просто текстовый файл, потом написал метод который распознает этот текст и закидывает данные обратно в коллекцию , для моих текущих задач этого хватает...

Answer (score 0):

на другой ветке форума наткнулся на такой же вопрос
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794500/serialize-javafx-model-with-gson
кому интересно можно почитать варианты решения...
я понял что нету смысла полностью сохранять весь ObservableList так как он содержит кучу дополнительной информации (ссылки, переменные и т.д.) сохраненный json получается не читабельный и теряется этот бонус.